# How to pass data (converted to json) from route to jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, routes

I am trying to pass a JSON file fetched from an API going to jQuery. I am trying to create an infinite scroll feature using jQuery before rendering it into an EJS file. The problem is that every time res.json(data) is being used, the screen renders all the JSON data coming from the API instead of an error since I didn't do `res.render('routeHere')`. The reason why I decided to pass the data to jQuery is that I cant do the infinite scroll in my route since the API has no pagination option.

```
app.get("/crypto", function(req, res){
axios.get('{apiURL}')
.then(data => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.json(data);

}).catch(error => {
    res.json(error)
})
```

I also set up body-parser for this thinking it might help.

```
app.use(express.json()); // JSON body parser middleware
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // URL-encoded body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

Now, in my jQuery, Its in a static folder and what I wanted to achieve is jQuery should be the one who will render it.

```
function fetchMoreData() {
        loadingData = true;
        loading.show();
        // Simulate API request
        $.getJSON('/crypto', function(data) {
            // Assuming '.lists' is the container where you want to append crypto names
            data.forEach(crypto => {
                const cryptoName = crypto.name;
                $('.lists').append(`<p class="crypto-name">${cryptoName}</p>`);
            });
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.error('Error fetching crypto data:', textStatus, errorThrown);
        });
fetchMoreData()
```

I tried to explain my problem as much as I could and please excuse me if some of my sentences are not understandable because English is not my first language. Thanks!

Comment: The question is unclear. Do you get the data in the frontend? What is the actual problem/question?

Comment: @jabaa - I got the data from an API, I already managed to transfer that data to res.json(data) and passed it to jQuery using ajax function. The API that I am using however is unable to set pages, limit, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to solve this problem. The reason why it is rendering JSON data is because I used the route that is supposed to render an EJS file rather than creating a new route for the said API to be converted next and to be used by jQuery.

```
app.get("/get_crypto", function(req, res){
axios.get('{apiURL}')
.then(data => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.json(data); // JSON data and will be modified by jQuery before displaying it to the EJS file.

}).catch(error => {
    res.json(error)
})

app.get("/crypto", function(req, res){
    res.render('crypto'); // crypto.ejs
})
```